# Add unique value only

Tags: mysql

I have tried using the following code to try and only enter a unique domain in the database.

```
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO domains2 (domain)
values ('$query2')";
print "running query: <br/>\n$query<br/>\n";
mysql_query($query, $link)
or die ("INSERT error:" .mysql_error());
```

For example if it tries to enter test.com/test.php and its already in the table it wont do it. However It still adds the data onto the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have a `UNIQUE` key on the `domain` field for this to work.

Comment: Or, if it's the only column, a PRIMARY KEY. No table should be without them.